# XML и (X)HTML отличия?

Tags: xml, html

HTML знаю,хотелось бы просто узнать различия.

И советы в использовании.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А погуглить ?... Википедия : [XML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) и [XHTML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)

Если в двух словах, то XML - просто набор правил для хранения структурированной информации. Любой информации вообще. HTML - язык разметки гипертекста - в принципе, хранит информацию о разметке страницы. HTML может быть и не валидным XML, то есть, не соответствовать правилам - и браузер все равно его скушает и отобразит. А XHTML уже должен быть валидным.
А различия между XML и HTML - ну.. это разные вещи в принципе, хотя XHTML - это подмножество XML.
В принципе, если Вам понятие XML не особо знакомо, то, возможно, это все кажется полной абстракцией. Читайте книги или хотя бы статьи - всего в интернете навалом.

Comment: Уже прочитал, вопрос можно считать закрытым.
Кстати, в Википедии слишком научными терминами перегружен, я не просто так ведь спрашиваю, есть ведь люди, которые поняли и могут поделится.

Comment: "А погуглить ?..." - С такими заявлениями вам надо на обычных форумах нудеть, Хэшкод - это сервис вопросов и ответов, одни задают вопросы, а другие отвечают (дают ссылки), а не посылают погуглить (меня эта фраза нереально бесит, как будто я совсем дебил и не поискал перед тем как спрашивать). На крайний случай давайте ссылку на страницу гугла с выдачей.